# Set Freestyle line thickness using python script

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, freestyle

I have enabled the freestyle SVG add-on.  I can set the 'Line thickness' in the 'Render' tab.  But, I would like to change this value using a python script.  I can't find an example of this.

Does anyone know how to change the line thickness via script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mouse over a field in blender it, amongst other things, gives you the script path

[image]

```
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.line_thickness
```

For most scripts we use `context`.  If we are in scene "Scene" it is the context scene, rather than look it up from `bpy.data.scenes`

```
import bpy
from bpy import context # for testing
scene = context.scene
#set line thickness to 2.0
scene.render.line_thickness = 2.0
```

Or in the python console, where `C = bpy.context` for convenience.

```
>>> C.scene.render.line_thickness
1.0

>>> C.scene.render.line_thickness = 3.0
```

Comment: Stupidly, I never actually noticed that! (Ohps.)  - Thankyou.